# Why is my @font-face not working after numerous effort?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I just don't get it. I have tried everything but it just won't work. I have looked up multiple tutorials and still it just won't work at all.

**CSS**

```
@font-face { 
   font-family: Note; 
   src: url('font/note_this-webfont.woff') format ('embedded-opentype'),
   url('font/note_this-webfont.woff')
} 

.note-editable {
   width: 260px;
   height: 130px;
   padding-top: 20px;
   margin-top: 60px;
   margin-left: 56px;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: Note;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Where did you put your css file?

Comment: it's in my main folder

Comment: can you give the full path

Comment: css: C:\Users\Salih-PC\Google Drive\Web Development\Stickynote                                                            font: C:\Users\Salih-PC\Google Drive\Web Development\Stickynote\font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to add the semicolon at the end ";" ...if not it's definitely a path error to the file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Note;
    src: url('font/note_this-webfont.woff') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('font/note_this-webfont.woff');
}
```